# Ищу символ (html entities) скрытого знака (секретного, спрятанного)

Tags: html, icon

Облазил справочники в интернете, замучал Гугл, но не могу найти иконку или символ "скрытого знака". Я такой встречал в интернете и приложениях,..

Выглядит он как будто бы букву закрасили прямоугольником из серых точек, что вот потри или наведи и там появится буква. Почти как в кино : "засекречено" "не для посторонних глаз" Но это не черная полоска врезанная в строку, а прямо можно разглядеть каждый символ отдельно (такие серые прямоугольники). Чаще всего приглядевшись можно увидеть, что они как будто из множества серых точек нанесенных методом Бендей.

В играх где надо слово угадать, иногда такие используют.

(Не знаю, как объяснить лучше)

искал следующие запросы: hide symbol, secret symbol, hide icon, secret icon, dotted icon, dotted symbol...

На крайний случай, конечно я могу сделать css такой. Но на 99% уверен что видел сущность или символ такой, и очень хотел бы его разыскать.

Спасибо, за помощь.

Comment: "Выглядит он как будто бы букву закрасили серыми точками" - Вы имеете в виду текст, поверх которого какое-то подобие blur или smooth? Или это непосредственно иконка? Если иконка, то что на ней изображено под слоем "серых точек"?

Comment: @nikitar это иконка или символ. Под ней ничего не видно. Она сама выглядит как прямоугольник из серых точек.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос не относиться ни к программированию ни системному администрированию...

Comment: @Air  но мне всё же интересно о каком символе речь ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) Вам в руки!

```
U+2591  ░   Light shade

U+2592  ▒   Medium shade

U+2593  ▓   Dark shade
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]